# Sending fax via asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net

i'm trying to send faxes with a asp.NET (C#) program , Can you please suggest any reliable third party control . Need to generate PDF and send it via Fax in my web application.

Any pointers and suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use itextsharp for creating PDFs during a pagelifecycle. its pretty easy to create a pdf with it, and then send it by whatever interface you want? maybe email to fax, or spool directory of some fax software.

i use the spool directory of gfi faxmaker. after fax is send, there is a status file which could be parsed for handling the success / failure of sendings.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to do this is to use a third party email to fax service like efax - all you then have to do is to create a document that efax can cope with (which includes HTML so you can generate your pages by any number of means - we used XML rendered by XSLT) and email it to the appropriate address. The downside is that there is a minimum level of fixed cost associated with using the service in addition to per fax costs based on the destination.

For any other solution you're going to need to have a system, under your control, that has a fax modem (or equivalent functionality?) that you can use to send. If it were me, I'd probably wrap the "send fax" capability up in a service (I expect WCF) - and then send the service the document you want to fax and the destination number, gives you a nice separation of concerns and scope for scaling at either end of the service. In fact I'd make the client end an interface and pluggable into your web app so you can choose to use the likes of efax or your own system or whatever else as appropriate without having to completely rebuild your app each time.